# How to Show Wordpress Pages only to logged in Users?

Tags: wordpress

What can i do to hide my pages (Navigation) on the login page. So that it only shows up when a user is logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do that by setting visibility on the page edit view. 
[image]

Comment: But that will make it public. I want that only logged in users can see all the tabs.

Comment: Also in future there may be a requirment to add some kind of qualifying logic to tabs. Users of a particular type can see the changes.

Comment: Don't publish it make it private and click on ok. So only private (logged in users) can show this post.